# Spring security default target url

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to reload the current page when a user is successfully authenticated with spring security. What should be the default-target-url or do I have to create a custom authentication entry point class? Some sample code would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

`<security:form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/home.htm"/>`

login.htm is my application's mapping for the login page, and home.htm is the default account home page, shown to users if they hit the login.htm url directly.

If the user hits any url other than login.htm or home.htm, which needs the user to be logged in, Spring security shows the login page, and after logging in, the user is taken to the url originally requested. You don't have to do anything special.

As an additional check, make sure you don't have `always-use-default-target="true"` in the config, this will force Spring Security to always show the default target url after logging in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, what I meant is the page can be accessed by anyone but when they do some action on the page, a login dialog box opens up if the user is not logged in. At that when the user is authenticated with spring security, I want the same page to reload. This is implemented on my pages on my website. So I cant fix the value of default-target-url. I hope this time I am more clear

Comment: I would like to see how you've setup ajax login using spring security.

Comment: Yeah I got it. I had to create a class implementing a AuthenticationSucessHandler,  which is called just after the authentication. Thanks for the reply